# Ambiguous match found, simply dropping Infragistics XamMonthCalendar onto WPF dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, infragistics

I'm getting an AmbiguousMatchException when I drop the control onto the form.  I suspect this is because it is finding both a WPF3 and a WPF4 version of the control, but I can't figure out where it's getting the WPF4 version from.

I do have the WPF4 suite installed on my development machine, but have checked the GAC and all referenced directories and have not found a reference to the WPF4 version.

Could something else be causing this error?  Any ideas on how to dive deeper into this issue?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT - I removed everything from the toolbox and it seemed to work, but when I restarted Visual Studio the error came back.  I now have no references in the project, toolbox, or GAC to the WPF4 stuff and it's still happening.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The error happens when you have two versions of the assembly or a dependent assembly.  This would happen by using both the WPF3 and WPF4 assemblies, it could also happen if you have references from two different volumes of NetAdvantage.

check your references and verify that you are referencing all WPF3 or all WPF4 assemblies from the NetAdvantage tool set and verify that the versions are also all consistent.

You could also check what version is being referenced in the toolbox to make sure it matches the references in your project.